# Format deconstruction in React to "push" to the left

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm currently using the default React eslint rules

Is there a way to make the deconstruction to be "pushed" to the left?

Instead of this:

```
export function useSomething<T = string | undefined>({
                                                       somethingA,
                                                       compareFunction = (prev, next) => prev === next,
                                                       timeout = 100,
                                                       parser = (value) => value,
                                                     }): T {
  return (undefined as unknown) as T;
}
```

It should be this:

```
export function useSomething<T = string | undefined>({
  somethingA,
  compareFunction = (prev, next) => prev === next,
  timeout = 100,
  parser = (value) => value
}): T {
  return (undefined as unknown) as T;
}
```